# Unable to use GetIntExtra integer value in for calculation

Tags: android, string, integer

MainClass.java

```
                Intent i;
                i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Next.class);
                i.putExtra("increment1",1);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Next.java

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int age=mIntent.getIntExtra("increment1", 0);
        String age1=Integer.toString(age);
        Toast.makeText(this,age1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

When I use variable age in my toast I'm getting below error. That means, I can't use Integer value. Please help me to use the Integer value.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{test.myapplication/test.myapplication.Next}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:380)
                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4564)
                                                                      at test.myapplication.Next.onCreate(Next.java:28)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6298)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2608)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? If you pass an int as the message argument to the `Toast.makeText()` it will assume you are passing a string resource id. The field "age" is actually an int.

Comment: Agree with Droidman. What is your issue? What are you trying to do? I do not see any code, where you are trying to do any "calculation" as you state in your title.